Error during replication of results in article Evidence for the utility of quantum computing
I am a newbie to quantum computing and Qiskit. I tried practise myself with research paper called  Evidence for the utility of quantum computing before fault tolerance. I run it successfully but the problem is in post-process and plotting. My output does not match the research paper output. I don't know where I made a mistake. I also tried it twice and I also get code from an author of a video (see link below) but with the same erroneous result.
Reference video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35ykEg3fG4c&list=PLOFEBzvs-VvrgHZt3exM_NNiNKtZlHvZi&index=5
My code link:
https://github.com/keyanskv/quantum

Above is my result

Above is the author result

Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. I would recommend testing the code on the simulator firstly.

Thank for command to me and i seek any help that a resource or guide for simulator to apply my code.

I've noticed two minor typos in your code.

YGate is used when making SYdgGate

current:
SYdgGate = UnitaryGate(YGate().inverse(), label = r'$\sqrt{y}^dag$')

change that to :
SYdgGate = UnitaryGate(SYGate.inverse(), label = r'$\sqrt{y}^dag$')


The same value, namely num_trotter_steps, is passed to generate_1d_tfim_circuit()

current :
qc_list = []
for trotter_step in range(max_trotter_steps):
    qc =generate_1d_tfim_circuit(num_qubits, num_trotter_steps,rx_angle,num_cls_bits= len(measured_qubits),trotter_barriers=True,layer_barriers=True)
    append_mirrored_1d_tfim_circuit(qc,num_qubits,num_trotter_steps,rx_angle,trotter_barriers=True,layer_barriers=True)

change that to :
qc_list = []
for trotter_step in range(max_trotter_steps):
    qc =generate_1d_tfim_circuit(num_qubits, trotter_step,rx_angle,num_cls_bits= len(measured_qubits),trotter_barriers=True,layer_barriers=True)
    append_mirrored_1d_tfim_circuit(qc,num_qubits,trotter_step,rx_angle,trotter_barriers=True,layer_barriers=True)


Thanks for reply your suggestion that help to clear my problem.Once again Thank you
